# Prove such a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$A$ is a nonempty closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f,g \colon A\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, prove that$\{x\in A：f(x)-g(x) \le 0\}$ is a closed set.

I know I can prove the complement open, but have no idea how to use this:
$f(x)-g(x)\le 0$ condition; please show me some details, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Outline:**

Define $h = f-g$: it is a function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

- $h$ is continuous. (why?)
- $(-\infty, 0]$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ (why?)
- $\{x\in A\mid f(x)-g(x) \leq 0\}=h^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$.

Can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm a beginner with this. A silly question: what do you mean by h^−1

Comment: The reciprocal set: f^1({y}) is the set of all x such that f(x)=y.